# Is it good process to use SSL AND Cloudflare simultaneously?

Tags: ssl, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

A few months ago I created the following website for my company: [www.mydomain.co.uk](http://www.mydomain.co.uk). I created it using Lightsail / Bitnami and as part of this process I created an SSL using the 'LetEncrypt' tool. I have also got Cloudflare set up which is providing a SSL/TLS encryption.
Website was live for a number of months and yesterday it stopped working - I suspect this is because the Bitnami SSL certificate had expired. So I set the Cloudflare SSL/TLS setting from 'Full (Strict' to 'Full' and it works fine now.

So do I need to renew the SSL certificate? Or is it obsolete as I am using Cloudflare?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

The SSL provided by Cloudflare only protects the connection between the client and Cloudflare, but not between Cloudflare and your server. To protect this connection you need SSL on your own server, i.e. using SSL here is not obsoleted by using Cloudflare.

The chance that some attacker is between the client and Cloudflare though is much higher than an attacker being between Cloudflare and your server. In the server the attacker is usually near the client, i.e. typically in the same network like in an open WiFi hotspot or by creating a rogue hotspot. Not much effort and expertise is needed for this kind of attacks. Contrary to this infiltrating connections between Cloudflare and your host is much harder, but government or other attackers with more resources can do it.

Full security does not check the certificate and thus only protects against passive sniffing of the connections. It does not protect against active man in the middle attacks where the attacker intercepts the traffic, decrypts it so it can be read and modified and clear and the re-encrypts again. To protect against such an attack a properly valid certificate has to be used and Cloudflare need to be configured to validate it properly, i.e. full strict. While active attacks need more access the network than passive attacks they are not out of scope for advanced attackers. So better use a valid certificate and switch on full strict.